# Ubuntu server 18.04 periodically crashing

Tags: server, 18.04, crash, plex, rclone

My server keeps periodically crashing and I am unable to figure out why.
It never used to do it and has only happened since it has been moved into a data center.

R clone and plex media server are on the server and I am not sure if they are causing the crash.

System logs. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tCRQ3jHH7S/

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. This 18.04 server was an upgrade, not a clean install, correct? I see ureadahead, and plex issues. How much RAM? Show me `free -h`. Do you know how to run memtest?

Comment: no this was a clean install. has 110gb of ram which is nowhere near full at the time of the crash.

Comment: here is ls -al /var/crash https://imgur.com/a/HU9kU3F

Comment: I see two crashes on May 17th. How often does this machine crash? Do you really have 110G RAM? Do you know how to `fsck` your disks? Do you know how to review `syslog` looking for, say, memory errors? Do you know how to run `memtest`?

Comment: Got through around 50gb in a mem test then it stopped working.

Comment: Yes i do have 110gb of ram https://imgur.com/a/J9KA2iv

Comment: Show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Although it'll take a long time, go ahead and rerun memtest. Get the free version from memtest86.com. Report back.

Comment: Use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your current BIOS level. Then go to the manufacturor's web site to check if there's a newer one.